# How to prove that $k \cdot |I| \leq |\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i|$ for each $I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let ${\cal X} = (X_1,...,X_n)$ be a family of subsets of a set $S$ and let $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$.
I konw the following expression for function $r$: $$r(U) = \min_{I' \subseteq \{1,...,n\}} \{n - |I'| + |\bigcup_{i \in I'}(X_i \cap U)|\}$$
I know that
$k \cdot (r(S) - r(U)) \leq |S-U|$ for each $U \subseteq S$.

Moreover, since $S - \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i \subseteq S$ for each $I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$, we have that

$$k \cdot (r(S) - r(S-\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i)) \leq |\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i|$$ for each $I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$.

How I can to show that $k \cdot |I| \leq |\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i|$ for each $I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The conditions listed so far allow $X_1=\ldots =X_n=\emptyset$ (so $r(U)=0$ for all $U$).